# How to change field value when grouping in elasticsearch, using regular expression to remove some information?

Tags: elasticsearch, etl

I have a string field which contains strings like:

```
"operation XYZ [1.1]" 
"operation XYZ [16.1]"
"Operation ABC [22.3]"
"Operation ABC [12.34]"
```

When I group this set of information, if give me four buckets, but I need to remove the trailing " [...]" and make ElasticSearch to group only the operation itself, in this case, it must return only two buckets.

Reading the ElasticSearch documentation, I've found:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

With apparently the following syntax:

```
POST operations*/_search
{
    "aggs": {
        "operation": {
            "filter": {
                "regexp": {
                  "de_operation": {
                    "value": "REGULAR EXPRESSION",
                  }
                }
            }}
```

I Tried the following example:

```
POST operations*/_search
{
    "aggs": {
        "operation": {
            "filter": {
                "regexp": {
                  "de_operation": {
                    "value": "^(.*) \[.*\]$"
                  }
                }
            }, ...}
```

But the outcome is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "json_parse_exception",
        "reason": "Unrecognized character escape '[' (code 91)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@2360ea24; line: 7, column: 40]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "json_parse_exception",
    "reason": "Unrecognized character escape '[' (code 91)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@2360ea24; line: 7, column: 40]"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

I know the error is on \[\], but the question is: Is this possible to group data based on a regular expression transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Just to help others here, I've managed to find a solution with a Help from my Friend Caio Paulluci.

When using painless language you can execute some java code and use some functions it provides, in this case I converted the object to string then manipulate it using native functions

```
POST operations*/_search
    "aggs": {
        "operation": {
            "terms": {
               "script": """ 
                    String o = doc.de_operation.toString();
                    String t = o.substring(1,orig.length()-1);
                    int indexOf = t.indexOf(' [');
                    return indexOf < 0 ? t : t.substring(0,indexOf);
               """,
               "size": 200000,
               "order": {
                  "_key": "desc"
               }
            }
```

For some reason, when converting from the original cast to string, it encloses the string with '[]', I'll dig further to find why and later I'll post the result here.
Another point is I've not found any performance issues with this approach, it seems to add a minor overhead to the whole operation.